# How to synchronize the time between the clients in an online game

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, synchronization, client-server

I am making an online multiplayer game in NodeJS where players have to guess the correct answer to a puzzle as fast as possible. The game is played through multiple rounds of 1 minute each (similar to [skribbl.io](http://skribbl.io)). Between every round is a 10 seconds pause where the Scoreboard is displayed. If every player has found the answer before the time is up, the round ends immediately.

When a player's client fetches the game, the server sends how much time there is remaining to the current round, based on when it started and the server's time. Every player's client has a local timer for rounds and the 10-seconds pause between them. A client's timer is initialized using the remaining time sent by the server. When a player's timer is up or when there is a websocket notification that says that the round has ended, the client shows that the round has ended.

For the first round to begin, the person that created the game clicks on a button to tell the server to create a new round and a puzzle. The server then sends a websocket notification to the players of this game that a round has started.

My problem is this: The rounds have to start and end at the same time for every player. After the first round, a puzzle for the next round has to be created, so the server has to know that it should create a new round with a puzzle and tell the players via websocket that a new round has started. Because I could eventually deploy my game on multiple servers (clusterize it), I want my server to be stateless, so I don't want the back-end to keep timers for every game that is being played.

Do you have any ideas on how this problem could be solved?

Thank you,

Comment: I am dubious that there is any way to accomplish this without the server acting as the source of truth for maintaining game state, but perhaps someone will have an approach from you; I look forward to reading the answers posted here.

Comment: I would make a request to a shared time server to synchronize local clock. Maybe this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol#Clock_synchronization_algorithm will give you ideas how to do it

Comment: @gonzalo Thanks for your comment! I could do that, but my server kind of already acts as the time server since it's the one which calculates the remaining times when the rounds are fetched. My problem is more that the server has to initiate rounds, but without keeping timers in its memory.

Comment: I'm thinking about a solution: 
The server will keep who of the players is the leader. When the leader finishes, send a notification through the websocket that the server replies to the other users that round has finished
This way the leader control when a round start and when it finishes but it's kind of insecure, because the leader can control the flow of the game. What do you think?

Comment: @gonzalo - that's an interesting idea, and I also think you've identified the primary problem with what I believe is any stateless server approach-- you can try to use the clocks of the users, but as soon as you do so you open the possibility for users to start futzing with the data they transmit to game the system.  If that's an acceptable risk, then something like this is an acceptable approach.

Comment: Other approach is use a shared memory server, that all your servers can share rounds. This way you don't store anything in the server, and whenever a server requires information would ask for it to shared memory server. (I was thinking of a redis server)

Comment: @gonzalo Hi gonzalo and sorry for the delay!  I think it has to work like you said. Right now, the leader of the game is the person who created it. But, as you pointed out, this person now controls the flow of the game. If they quit the game or lose the connection or whatever else, then there will be no next round. If they decide to trick the system and start a round ahead of time, then other players will have their rounds cut short. I think the "leader" approach is the right one for a stateless back-end, but it means there are a few mechanisms that need to be put in place for it to work.

Comment: For example, a heartbeat system where clients send their connection status to the back-end.
I'm not sure about the shared memory server, because the back-end would still need to trigger the round creations on timers.